# Platform Term 7.d - App Settings Platform URLs are broken - facebook

Tags: facebook

I am developing a website, and I want to add a Facebook login button, but the problem is that I am getting this message no matter what I do, I fixed all broken URLs, and this message still hasn't disappeared. It is even not clear what I should do other than fix my website URLs and then what?

I saw some questions mention deleting the app and restoring it back again, but mine is not an application it is merely a website.

[image]

Comment: _"but mine is not an application it is merely a website."_ - then you should check that the URL you entered for the Website platform is reachable by the debug tool.